# Dump some tables of databases for each database using MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running many joomla websites on a web server.
I want to backup my web sites' databases but not all. I only want to backup `tablePrefix_users` and `tablePrefix_content` tables only.

Table prefixes are different for each database. Is that possible with a query? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

try this script when you just wanna dump specific tables :

```
SCHEMA=mydb
SQL="SET group_concat_max_len = 10240;"
SQL="${SQL} SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_name separator ' ')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='${SCHEMA}'"
SQL="${SQL} AND table_name IN ('tab1','tab2','tab3')"
TABLE_LIST=`mysql -u... -p... -AN -e"${SQL}"`
mysqldump -uXX -pXX ${SCHEMA} ${TABLE_LIST} > myschema_tables.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Up_One says looks ok but I would change line 5 from:

```
SQL="${SQL} AND table_name IN ('tab1','tab2','tab3')"
```

to:

```
SQL="${SQL} AND (table_name like ('%_users') OR table_name like ('%_content'))"
```